# Linux delete spaces after a character in a line

Tags: linux, replace, sed

In Linux, if I have a file with entries like:

> My Number is = 1234; #This is a random number

Can I use sed or anything else to replace all spaces after '#' with '+', so that the output looks like:

> My Number is = 1234; #This+is+a+random+number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way using `awk`:

```
awk -F# 'OFS=FS { gsub(" ", "+", $2) }1' file.txt
```

Result:

```
My Number is = 1234; #This+is+a+random+number
```

**EDIT:**

After reading comments below, if your file contains multiple `#`, you can try this:

```
awk -F# 'OFS=FS { for (i=2; i <= NF; i++) gsub(" ", "+", $i); print }' file.txt
```

Comment: The `1` is an expression that evaluates to true, causing the current line to be printed.  It's a short-cut for `{print}`.

Comment: While this answer is a nice example of awk, I'm not 100% sure it meets the OP's requirements.  What if there is another `#` in the line?

Comment: replace `gsub(" ", "+", $2)` with `for (i=2;i<=NF;++i) gsub(" ", "+", $i)` and it will handle any number of `#` chars

Comment: Also, the `1` trick is nice for code golf, but in general I think a simple `; print` inside the curlies would be clearer.

Comment: @ghoti, Point noted. I made some assumptions about the OP's input.

Comment: @MarkReed, Yes a `for` loop as you describe would fix it. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in pure shell...

```
$ foo="My Number is = 1234; #This is a random number"
$ echo -n "${foo%%#*}#"; echo "${foo#*#}" | tr ' ' '+'
My Number is = 1234; #This+is+a+random+number
$
```

Capturing this data to variables for further use is left as an exercise for the reader.  :-)

Note that this also withstands multiple # characters on the line:

```
$ foo="My Number is = 1234; #This is a # random number"
$ echo -n "${foo%%#*}#"; echo "${foo#*#}" | tr ' ' '+'
My Number is = 1234; #This+is+a+#+random+number
$
```

Or if you'd prefer to create a variable rather than pipe through `tr`:

```
$ echo -n "${foo%%#*}#"; bar="${foo#*#}"; echo "${bar// /+}"
My Number is = 1234; #This+is+a+#+random+number
```

And finally, if you don't mind subshells with pipes, you could do this:

```
$ bar=$(echo -n "$foo" | tr '#' '\n' | sed -ne '2,$s/ /+/g;p' | tr '\n' '#')
$ echo "$bar"
My Number is = 1234; #This+is+a+#+random+number
$
```

And for the fun of it, here's a short `awk` solution:

```
$ echo $foo | awk -vRS=# -vORS=# 'NR>1 {gsub(/ /,"+")} 1'
My Number is = 1234; #This+is+a+#+random+number
#$
```

Note the trailing ORS.  I don't know if it's possible to avoid a final record separator.  I suppose you could get rid of that by piping the line above through `head -1`, assuming you're only dealing with the one line of input data.

Comment: I think that to use awk, you'd have to do the `for` loop as steve proposed.

Answer (score 2):

Not terrible efficient, but:

```
perl -pe '1 while (s/(.*#[^ ]*) /\1+/);'
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
echo 'My Number is = 1234; #This is a random number' | 
sed 's/#/\n&/;h;s/.*\n//;y/ /+/;H;g;s/\n.*\n//'
My Number is = 1234; #This+is+a+random+number
```

Comment: **+1** - Great, I was hoping somebody would demonstrate this with a hold buffer.  :)  Alas, in BSD sed it breaks badly if there's a second `#` on the line. (But you did mention GNU, so you keep your +1!)

Comment: @ghoti thanks, I'm surprised that a second `#` causes a problem (even for BSD). Usually the `\n`'s are the ones at fault in other sed's. Could you have added a `g` to the substitute command in translation?

Answer (score 1):

Here is yet another `perl` one-liner:

```
echo 'My Number is = 1234; #This is a random number' \
| perl -F\# -lane 'join "#", @F[1,-1]; s/ /+/g; print $F[1], "#", $_'
```

- `-F` specifies how to split string into `@F` array.
- `-an` wraps stdin with:

```perl
while (<>) {
  @F = split('#');
  # code from -e goes here
}
```

Comment: It also breaks if there are extra `#` characters.  Try it with: `'My Number is = 1234; #This is a random # number` to see.

Comment: Right forgot about the separator, will fix it shortly.

Comment: The fix maintains the first separator, but still doesn't help with the alternate string I posted.